# How to temporarily enlarge font size on hover using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi There Just Ran Into A Small Problem i have a column with text in it and i have evoked some code that makes the font of the text get bigger when hovering over the column

```
$("#column3").hover(function(){
    $("p").css("fontSize", "30px");

});
```

but how do i get the font to return back to the original size.

I hope this is not a stupid question You guys.

Honestly i have spent a miserable 12 minutes looking through past threads about the issue i am going through Thanks.

Sorry If it is a dumb one

Comment: pass a 2nd callback to hover() that undoes the style.

Comment: Could You Give me an example Thanks

Comment: @SamOpoku. Did you try the CSS suggestion yet? And did it help?

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS instead, and spare yourself the javascript headache:

```
<style>
    #column3 p {font-size: 10px}
    #column3 p:hover {font-size: 30px}
</style>
```

If on the other hand you want to enlarge ALL `p`s within the container, when hovering over the *container itself*, you could place the the `:hover` on the container, like so:

```
<style>
    #column3 p {font-size: 10px}
    #column3:hover p {font-size: 30px}
</style>
```

Note the ever so subtle difference!

Meanwhile, in javascript, make sure the javascript is inactive while you test it out:

```
<script>
    /*
    $("#column3").hover(function(){
        $("p").css("fontSize", "30px");
    });
    */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work and I have a fiddle below to prove it.. any questions?

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
        var size = $("#column3").css("fontSize");
        $("#column3").hover(
                function(){
                    $(this).css("fontSize", "30px");
                }, 
                function(){
                    $(this).css("fontSize", size);
                }
         );
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="column3">test</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbxsf2t0/

**EDIT** if you want to change the size of  the `p` specifically .

```
      var size = $("#column3").css("fontSize");
        $("#column3").hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find("p").css("fontSize", "30px");
                }, 
            function(){
                $(this).find("p").css("fontSize", size);
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the font-size you gotta use "font-size". Have a look in below js code

```
$("#column3").hover(function(){
  $('p').css("font-size","30px");
});
```